# Buildozer apk file with pyaudio does not show up

Tags: python, kivy, pyaudio, buildozer

I am working on android app using pyaudio, kivy and buildozer
here it is my imports

```
from functools import partial
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.scrollview import ScrollView
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import StringProperty
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.image import Image
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.core.window import Window
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyaudio
```

and here it is buildozer.spec requirements

```
requirements = python3,certifi,charset-normalizer,Cython,docutils,idna,Kivy,Kivy-Garden,pip,PyAudio,Pygments,requests,setuptools,SpeechRecognition,urllib3
```

but after converting my project to apk file, my app does not show up(

I was trying to find any ways to solve my problems but I couldn't

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.